# Update partial view in Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC project with C#.
Ok so I have a layout view where I put my partial view which contains just a div that displays notification messages.

Now from some view I have a button that generate a report in 5 minutes in async manner. While the report being generated I need to allow the user to use other areas of the website.

My action method, once the report is generated successfully, simply returns a string "Success", o/w "Fail".
What I want to do is assign that returned string to the div of the partial view which is on the layout page. So this way the user can see the notification from wherever he is within the website.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of different things going on here. First, you want the server to update the user with the "success" or "fail" status. This requires 1) using web sockets to create a persistent connection between the client and server, allowing the server to talk to the client without requiring the client to first send a request, or 2) long-polling, which is means the client continuously sending requests at a defined interval to see if the server has any updates.

Long-polling (with AJAX) was the only way to achieve this before the advent of web sockets, which are relatively new, and not universally supported. In particular, IIS8+ is required on the server side, and client side, you need a modern browser, which is really any except IE 9 and below. If you can't run the site on IIS8+ or you need to support legacy versions of IE, then you're stuck with long-polling.

However, with either approach, you're tied to a single page. If the user navigates away, web socket connections are closed and long-polling stops. If the user is still on your site, the next page would need to re-establish all this functionality to keep it working. That's not really difficult - just something to be aware of. It just means that you'll need some universal script running on page load across your site for this.

Now as far as replacing the content of your "partial view" goes. You shouldn't look at it that way. I encourage you to read my post: [There's no such thing as a "partial view" client-side](http://cpratt.co/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-partial-view-client-side/), where I get into more detail. The TL;DR version is that all of this updating of the client is happening *client-side*, and at that point, all you have is the browser DOM. There's no concept of a "partial view". If you want to replace a part of the DOM, you must select it and manipulate it. That's all done with JavaScript and it's all on you. There's no easy "replace this partial view" button.